# How would i grey out the rest of the text in my table record when i select the 3rd option in my drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I'm currently trying to make my other table items grey out when i select the third option in my table menu which is called "closed" with an id of 3.

This is in the status drop down menu as seen here.

I'm trying to figure out how to make the CaseID, date, name, details and Status sections become greyed out, when the status part of the table record is "closed".

[image]

```
    <% include ../partials/header.ejs %> 

<% include ../partials/main_nav.ejs %> 



<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
  <div class="reportContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
      <h1 class="display-4">Incident Reports</h1>  
      
      
      <br />
      <!-- Details of the table and how to submit new reports -->
      <p>The information below is the current incident reports that have been submitted.<p>
       <p> To add a new report, click <a href="/reports/add">here</a> or use the <strong>Create a Report</strong> button below.<br>
          To edit a report, a report, use the Edit button.<br>
          To delete a report, click the <strong>Delete</strong> button. This is instant, permanent, and will not ask for confirmation.</p>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>CaseID</th>
              <th class="text-center">Date</th>
              <th class="text-center">Name</th>
              <th class="text-center">Details</th>
              <th class="text-center">Status</th>
              <th class="text-center"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <!-- Template Row -->

            <% for (let count = 0; count < incident_reports.length; count++) { %>
            <tr>
              <td ><div  id="creditcard"><%= incident_reports[count].caseID %></div></td>
              <td class="text-center"><div id="creditcard"><%= incident_reports[count].date %></div></td>
              <td class="text-center" ><div  id="creditcard"><%= incident_reports[count].name %></div></td>
              <td class="text-center" ><div  id="creditcard"><%= incident_reports[count].details %></div></td>
              <td class="text-center"><div id="creditcard">test<%= incident_reports[count].Status %></div></td>

              <td class="text-center">
                <a href="/reports/edit/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #f59e2e; border-color:#f59e2e;"
                  ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Edit</a
      >
      <a href="/reports/delete/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="background-color: #ff3e3e; color: white; border-color: #ff3e3e;">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>


        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn  dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Status
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" onChange="selectChanged()">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/reports/inprogress/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" id="payment-method" value="1">In Progress</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/reports/dispatched/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" id="payment-method" value="2">Dispatched</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/reports/closed/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" id="payment-method" value="3">Closed</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
  </main>
  <a href="/reports/add" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create a Report</a>

      <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 text-center">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
  function selectChanged() {
    var x = document.getElementById("payment-method").value;
    document.getElementById("creditcard").disabled = (x == 1);
  }
   
  </script>

<% include ../partials/bottom_nav.ejs %>

<% include ../partials/footer.ejs %>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you get access to status id when the page first load?

Comment: I'm pretty sure i do. I've modified the code to try and include <div> to make the text greyed out but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

add `data-status` attribute for every rows to keep track of current status.

```
...
<tbody>
  <!-- Template Row -->
  <% for (let count = 0; count < incident_reports.length; count++) { %>
    <tr data-status="<%= incident_reports[count].Status %>">
      <td>
        <span> <!--  add span tag to change text color. -->
        <%= incident_reports[count].caseID %>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center" for="payment-method">
        <span>
        <%= incident_reports[count].date %>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <span>
        <%= incident_reports[count].name %>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <span>
        <%= incident_reports[count].details %>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="text-center">
        <span>
        <%= incident_reports[count].Status %>
        </span>
      </td>

      <td class="text-center">
        <a href="/reports/edit/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #f59e2e; border-color:#f59e2e;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Edit</a
      >
      <a href="/reports/delete/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="background-color: #ff3e3e; color: white; border-color: #ff3e3e;">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>


        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn  dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Status
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" onChange="selectChanged()">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/reports/inprogress/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" id="1">In Progress</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/reports/dispatched/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" id="2">Dispatched</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/reports/closed/<%= incident_reports[count]._id %>" id="3">Closed</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <% } %>
</tbody>
...
```

**CSS**

add this rule in css to select `<tr>` that has `data-status="Closed"`.

```css
...
tbody tr[data-status="Closed"] td > span {
  color: gray;
}
...
```

Comment: getting there, still trying to implement it

Comment: I'm having a problem getting the id hmm

Comment: can't you do something like `incident_reports[count].status_id`?

Comment: i edited my answer. you can also use `incident_reports[count].Status`.

Comment: So i can use incident_reports[count].Status

Then just change the data status requirement in the css to this 

tbody .tr[data-status="Closed"] td > span {
  color: gray;
}

Comment: I'm still not getting the test color change in span, might be something wrong with my css, i could just use inline css in my ejs

Comment: maybe bootstrap is over riding it

Comment: add `!important` at the end of `color: gray;`.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yR5YxM7

for some reason it isn't implementing it

Comment: my apology. change `.tr` to just `tr` (remove the dot).

Comment: Yep that was the fix, thank you so much! sorry i went to sleep right after fixing it.